# how to use a variable that have been declared in if statement to use it back in the else statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, multiprocessing

So I am am using cluster and I am bit new to it, I want to get an input which has been declared inside an if statement and use it back in the else statement

```
Multi_processing = async() => {
  if (cluster. isMaster) {
    const name = await prompt(' input ');// input which want to be re used in else 
    console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);
    for (let i = 0; i <2; i++) {
      cluster.fork();
    
      console.log(name)
    }
    cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
      console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} finished`);
    });
  }
    else {
    console.log(name) // name is undefined
    console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started`);
  }
}
Multi_processing();
```

If you asking why I didn't put the variable in the else it just  do weird things like it continue asking for input  and I want to put it in the if statement so the input asked once not of how many times I forked the code

**EDIT** : just for explantion why i didnt  put the input outside the cluster.ismaster here is an image of what happens even the fork number is only 2
[image]

Comment: Why do you set a function local variable in the if block and read it in the else block? You have to store `name` somewhere else. You could create a class or a closure.

Comment: i set the the input in the if statement so it would be called only one time if i set it outside of the if block it would be called as many times as the op

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a closure to store `name` between the function calls and avoid global variables:

```
Multi_processing = (() => {
  let name;
  return async() => {
    if (cluster.isMaster) {
      name = await prompt(' input ');// input wich want to be re used in else 
      console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);
      for (let i = 0; i <2; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
        console.log(name)
      }
      cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
        console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} finished`);
      });
    } else {
      console.log(name) // name is undefined
      console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started`);
    }
  };
})();
Multi_processing();
```

Here is an example:

```js
Multi_processing = (() => {
  let name = null;
  return async() => {
    if (cluster.isMaster) {
      name = 'test';
    } else {
      if (name !== null) {
        console.log(name) // name is undefined
      }
    }
  };
})();

cluster = {isMaster: false}
Multi_processing();
cluster = {isMaster: true}
Multi_processing();
cluster = {isMaster: false}
Multi_processing();
```

Answer (score 1):

If block and Else block are different blocks. When you declare a variable inside an If block, the consecutive Else block does not recognize it. So you have to declare the variable in a common space. So that both If and Else block can recognize it.

Comment: hello, thank u for your comment i tried that  before to declare the variable out side  the if and else block, the problem is when the operation get forked it ask the same question as many times as the forked ops

Comment: You can tag it with a callback. Once the callback complete then you pass the value and trigger this block. Once prompt('input') successful to get the value then it will trigger Multi_processing